# UITableViewCell animation dissapears after user scrolls the UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am making a basic music streamer. In a view controller (PlayerViewController) I have a UITableView with custom UITableViewCell (called MediaItemTableViewCell). In the function cellForRowAtIndexPath I add the metadata about the current streaming music track and add an animation if the cell is the current playing song. This all works correctly and the animation is added.

The problem is if a user scrolls the UITableView at all then the animation dissapears. I have traced the code I have written and used breakpoints and NSLog to verify my variables are correct at every step. The animation even dissapears after scrolling if I set it to every cell all the time (as in, set animation outside of the if block).

Is there something wrong in my code or something going on in iOS that I am not seeing?

MediaItemTableViewCell:

```
 @interface MediaItemTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *track_title;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *artist;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *duration;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *sc_album_image;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *playing_animation;

@end
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath of my PlayerViewController:

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        MediaItemTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        MediaItem *track = [self.playlist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        _playListTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

        cell.track_title.text = track.track_title;
        cell.artist.text = track.artist;
        cell.duration.text = track.duration;
        cell.sc_album_image.image =  track.artwork;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        if((int)_current_track_index == (int)indexPath.row && _player.isPlaying)
        {
            cell.playing_animation.image = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"wave" duration:0.6f];
        }

        return cell;

    }
```

Comment: Is the if statement being executed? Can you put a breakpoint in there?

Comment: Rely on data rather than indexPath, it may change, best would be add a property in custom class which will have MediaItem, and your animation logic trigger.

Comment: where/how is `_current_track_index` being set?

Comment: The 'if' statement does execute. Once the animation is set, when the user scrolls and the program executes the cellForRowAtIndexPath function it does hit the if statement but the animation still will disappear sometime after the function returns. If I get rid of the if and put the animation on ever cell they all will disappear when the user scrolls.

Comment: _current_track_index is in a separate class called Player which handles the functionality while PlayerViewController handles the UI. I dont suspect this to be the issue because even without the if statement (so the program draws the animation on every cell) the animation(s) will still disappear upon scrolling the tableview

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by reworking how my animation is created. The following is the same if block in cellForRowAtIndexPath as before but with my updated code. Heavily in need of a refactor, this initial version works though:

```
if((int)_current_track_index == (int)indexPath.row && _player.isPlaying)
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.2];
    cell.song_index_label.text = @"";
    NSArray *imageNames = @[@"wave1.png", @"wave2.png", @"wave3.png", @"wave4.png", @"wave5.png", @"wave6.png", @"wave7.png"];

    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++) {
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }

    // Normal Animation
    cell.playing_animation.animationImages = images;
    cell.playing_animation.animationDuration = 0.6;
    [cell.playing_animation startAnimating];
}
```

The downside is every time the table is scrolled far enough the animation will restart and look clunky. Will have to refactor and come up with something better. Still not sure why my original attempt did not work as they should both be valid ways to add animation to cells. I liked the original code because it was more concise although it was very broken in terms of functionality.

Comment: Still not sure why this means works instead of the "animatedImageNamed", but this solved the problem for me too.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting an static image on playing_animation UIImageView.

Is your animation frame based?

Maybe you need to set the animationImages property of UIImageView. It is a NSArray of images and you can configure the duration and the number of repetitions with the properties animationDuration and animationRepeatCount.

Someting like:

```
if((int)_current_track_index == (int)indexPath.row && _player.isPlaying) {

    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_IF_IMAGES_IN_ANIMATION; ++i) {
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:"wave%d", i+1]];
    }

    cell.playing_animation.animationImages = images;
    cell.playing_animation.animationDuration = 0.6;
    [cell.playing_animation startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: My animation is frame based. 5 different images that all begin with "wave" and the command I used does display and animate properly except that the animation disappears after the user scrolls the tableview. No matter how I add the animation to the cell, after the user scrolls the table the animation disappears

Comment: Have you tried to create an array of UIImage and set this array to animationImages property of UIImageView?

Comment: Maybe this might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281597/uiimageview-animation-stopping-in-uitableview

Comment: Hey swallace, I realized after answering my question you might have been on to something. I took the long route in my answer and manually added all the images into the animationImages property. Still needs refactoring and the code is way uglier but so far it works

Comment: Any idea why this one method of adding animation works and the other doesnt?

Comment: No David, I have no idea :)
I always use the animationImages property instead set an unique image.
In your response below using the solution that I proposed you use an NSArray called imageNames with all names of images. I propose you to use something like:

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfImages; ++i) {
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat"wave%d", i+1]]];
}

You said that the animation restart, this is because the cell is reused. Try add the animation in the custom cell itself instead of cellForRowAtIndexPath.